# Laravel 9 and Zoho Writer Merge and Sign Intergration merge_data not found

Tags: json, laravel-9, zoho

I am having a problem with my Zoho Laravel Integration.

Using the Merge and Sign scope, I cannot fix the merge_data of the ZOHO API.

This is the documentation of ZOHO Merge and API: https://www.zoho.com/writer/help/api/v1/merge-and-sign.html

```
public function SendWaiver()
{
    $accessToken = $this->getAccessToken();
    \Log::info('Access Token: ' . $accessToken['access_token']);

    $response = Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Zoho-oauthtoken ' . $accessToken['access_token'],
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ])
        ->post('https://writer.zoho.com/api/v1/documents/kcrsoa321953c62f54fadba97ee1b525ef8c4/merge/sign', [
            'service_name' => 'zohosign',
            'filename' => 'Under Age Waiver',

            'signer_data' => json_encode([
                'recipient_1' => 'yfcrommelt@gmail.com',
                'action_type' => 'sign',
                'language' => 'en'
            ]),

            'merge_data' => json_encode([
                'data' => [
                    [
                        ' Gym_Name' => 'Gym1',
                        ' Member_Name' => 'Ryle Traya',
                        ' Parent_Name' => 'Rommel Traya',
                        ' Contact_Phone_Number' => '09771054119'
                    ]
                ]
            ])
        ]);

    \Log::info('Merge Data : ' . json_encode([
            'data' => [
                [
                    'Gym_Name' => 'Gym1',
                    'Member_Name' => 'Ryle Traya',
                    'Parent_Name' => 'Rommel Traya',
                    'Contact_Phone_Number' => '09771054119'
                ]
            ]
        ]));

    return response()->json($response->json(), $response->status());
}
```

And the output is:

```json
{
    "error_collection": [
        {
            "message": "Merge data not found. Please try again with proper merge data.",
            "documentation_url": "https://www.zoho.com/writer/help/api/v1/merge-api-possible-error-codes.html",
            "errorcode": "R6001"
        }
    ],
    "error": {
        "message": "Merge data not found. Please try again with proper merge data.",
        "documentation_url": "https://www.zoho.com/writer/help/api/v1/merge-api-possible-error-codes.html",
        "response_generated_time": 1694411379849,
        "request_url": "https://writer.zoho.com/api/v1/documents/kcrsoa321953c62f54fadba97ee1b525ef8c4/merge/sign",
        "errorcode": "R6001"
    }
}
```

But in my logs, the output is jsonly correct.

Help me with this.

I tried `json_encode`, I tried laravel 9 array. And my expectation is that my API Integration of Merge and Sign will be success since I am following the documentation

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I could suspect the below two cases:

#### Space character in Merge data keys:

There is a space at the start of the keys in `merge_data` JSON data like `<space>Gym_Name`. So is that intentional? If not, we could try removing that.

**Corrected Code:**

```php
json_encode([
                'data' => [
                    [
                        'Gym_Name' => 'Gym1',
                        'Member_Name' => 'Ryle Traya',
                        'Parent_Name' => 'Rommel Traya',
                        'Contact_Phone_Number' => '09771054119'
                    ]
                ]
            ])
```

#### Sending the data as form-data than JSON:

**Corrected Code:**

```php
Http::withHeaders([
        'Authorization' => 'Zoho-oauthtoken ' . $accessToken['access_token']
    ])
        -> asMultipart() # Setting form headers
        ->post('https://writer.zoho.com/api/v1/documents/docId/merge/sign', [
            'service_name' => 'zohosign',
            'filename' => 'Under Age Waiver',

            'signer_data' => json_encode([
                'recipient_1' => 'yfcrommelt@gmail.com',
                'action_type' => 'sign',
                'language' => 'en'
            ]),

            'merge_data' => json_encode([
                'data' => [
                    [
                        'Gym_Name' => 'Gym1',
                        'Member_Name' => 'Ryle Traya',
                        'Parent_Name' => 'Rommel Traya',
                        'Contact_Phone_Number' => '09771054119'
                    ]
                ]
            ])
        ]);
```